# Update multiple columns in the same statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume that I have the following database schema:
[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JefMn.png)

A student can have more than 2 grades in the same subject.

I want to update the columns highest_math_grade, highest_physic_grade, highest_chemistry_grade of table student. This is how I do it:

```
UPDATE student JOIN (
SELECT student.id, MAX(grade) AS grade
FROM student join grade
ON student.id = grade.student_id
WHERE subject = 'math'
GROUP BY student.id
  ) AS subquery
ON student.id = subquery.id
SET highest_math_grade = subquery.grade;

UPDATE student JOIN (
    SELECT student.id, MAX(grade) AS grade
    FROM student join grade
    ON student.id = grade.student_id
    WHERE subject = 'physic'
    GROUP BY student.id
  ) AS subquery
ON student.id = subquery.id
SET highest_physic_grade = subquery.grade;


UPDATE student JOIN (
    SELECT student.id, MAX(grade) AS grade
    FROM student join grade
    ON student.id = grade.student_id
    WHERE subject = 'chemistry'
    GROUP BY student.id
) AS subquery
ON student.id = subquery.id
SET highest_chemistry_grade = subquery.grade;
```

It is not nice that I have to use 3 update statements. I tried:

```
UPDATE student
  JOIN (SELECT *
        FROM grade
        ORDER BY grade) AS grade
    ON student.id = grade.student_id
SET highest_math_grade    = (CASE WHEN grade.subject = 'math'
  THEN grade.grade
                             ELSE highest_math_grade END),
  highest_chemistry_grade = (CASE WHEN grade.subject = 'chemistry'
    THEN grade.grade
                             ELSE highest_chemistry_grade END),
  highest_physic_grade    = (CASE WHEN grade.subject = 'physic'
    THEN grade.grade
                             ELSE highest_physic_grade END);
```

However, it only updates each student once which is not what I wanted.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with just one update statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer, Hope this helps you:

```
UPDATE S SET S.highest_math_grade=Math_Grade
    ,S.highest_chemistry_grade =chemistry_Grade
    ,S.highest_physic_grade=physic_Grade
FROM STUDENT S,(
    SELECT S.ID
        ,MAX(G1.grade)Math_Grade
        ,MAX(G2.grade)chemistry_Grade
        ,MAX(G3.grade)physic_Grade
    FROM STUDENT S
    LEFT JOIN Grade G1 ON S.id=G1.student_id AND G1.subject = 'math'
    LEFT JOIN Grade G2 ON S.id=G2.student_id AND G2.subject = 'chemistry'
    LEFT JOIN Grade G3 ON S.id=G3.student_id AND G3.subject = 'physic'
    GROUP BY S.ID
)D
WHERE S.ID=D.ID
```